# Syncing two salesforce instances daily

Tags: data-synchronization, multi-org

We have 2 separate salesforce CRMs.

The first one is called Enterprise. 
The 2nd one has some data from the enterprise imported (for further reporting and analytics).

The goal is to daily update the changes from the Enterprise to the 2nd salesforce instance, only for some specific objects.

Before writing any apex code to daily check for changes between the 2 instances, I wanted to see if there is already any solution or app that does this? Cause to me it looks like a common issue that might have been came up for others as well.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Salesforce to Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=business_network_managing_leads.htm&type=5) feature?

Comment: @DavidCheng No, thanks for sharing. By looking at the link seems like Salesforce to Salesforce has the issue that the record is shared. In our case it's more like one way path from Enterprise to 2nd salesforce. Changes on the 2nd salesforce can't and shouldn't make they way back to enterprise.

Comment: Maybe consider using [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) and have the external DB be the other Salesforce org?

Comment: Try https://sync.helpfulbits.com